Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D', because it does not exist or you do not have permission
I'm trying to set up merge replication but I get this error:
My permission is :
enter image description here
Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D', because it does not exist or you do not have permission
If I execute this query use testData
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D'; then the object
is my database admin user, what am I doing wrong?

2024-10-23 09:42:57.549 [87%] [0 sec remaining] Percent Complete: 87
2024-10-23 09:42:57.549 Creating replication triggers on table 'Employees'
2024-10-23 09:42:57.549 OLE DB Distributor 'DMITRY': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2024-10-23 09:42:57.817 Connecting to OLE DB Subscriber at datasource: 'ONLIMS', location: '', catalog: 'testData', providerstring: '' using provider 'MSOLEDBSQL'
2024-10-23 09:42:58.519 OLE DB Subscriber: ONLIMS
DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
Version: 16.00.1000
catalog name: testData
user name: dbo
API conformance: 0
SQL conformance: 0
transaction capable: 1
read only: F
identifier quote char: "
non_nullable_columns: 0
owner usage: 15
max table name len: 128
max column name len: 128
need long data len:
max columns in table: 1000
max columns in index: 16
max char literal len: 131072
max statement len: 131072
max row size: 131072
2024-10-23 09:42:58.932 initating deferred cmd exec
2024-10-23 09:42:58.932 exec sys.sp_MSaddmergetriggers N'Employees', N'dbo', null, 0deferred cmd exec completed
2024-10-23 09:42:59.155 Disconnecting from OLE DB Subscriber 'ONLIMS'
2024-10-23 09:42:59.288 The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may have been unable to create or write to the message file. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2024-10-23 09:42:59.288 OLE DB Subscriber 'ONLIMS': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2024-10-23 09:42:59.433 Percent Complete: 87
2024-10-23 09:42:59.433 The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may have been unable to create or write to the message file. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2024-10-23 09:42:59.433 OLE DB Distributor 'DMITRY': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2024-10-23 09:42:59.579 Percent Complete: 0
2024-10-23 09:42:59.579 Category:NULL
Source:  Merge Replication Provider
Number:  -2147201001
Message: The merge process was unable to deliver the snapshot to the Subscriber. If using Web synchronization, the merge process may have been unable to create or write to the message file. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2024-10-23 09:42:59.712 Percent Complete: 0
2024-10-23 09:42:59.712 Category:NULL
Source:  Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server
Number:  15151
Message: Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

When I connected to the subscriber and performed the required procedure:
exec sys.sp_MSaddmergetriggers N'Employees', N'dbo', null, 0
I got those an errors:
sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid object name '[dbo].[MSmerge_ins_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D]'
sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid object name '[dbo].[MSmerge_upd_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D]'
sp_MS_marksystemobject: Invalid object name '[dbo].[MSmerge_del_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D]'
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot find the object 'MSmerge_ctsv_9777E7338F8248498F9237E1FF3FE39D', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Failed to create merge replication triggers for object '[dbo].[Employees]'.
Completion time: 2024-10-23T13:46:35.7032508-04:00
